# React setState on an array of Objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a function which I am trying to change the properties of an object inside an array of objects at a particular index:

```
const handleEdit= (index) =>{
 if(itemList[index].edit==true){
  const copied=[...itemList];
  const item2 = {...itemList[1]};
  item2.edit= true;
  item2.Name='test';
  copied[index]=item2;
  setItemList(copied);
  console.log("correct",itemList);
}
```

When I look at the log, the "Name" property properly updates from it's previous value to "test" but the boolean "edit" property stays at it's previous value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what's happening here. You check for edit==true, copy item [1], set edit=true. Not sure how we're supposed to think about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Yes thanks edemain et. al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct, except for the `console.log` statement. You shouldn't expect `itemList` (or state in general) to update immediately when you call a state setter like `setItemList`. Setting state schedules a future update.

If you instead `console.log(itemList)` e.g. immediately after `itemList`'s declaration, you should see it updated.

Comment: As @DaveNewton wrote above, your code checks for `edit === true`, and in that case, sets `edit` to `true`.  That's not going to change the `edit` property...